# Transfer this.state value to other Class [React Native]

Tags: react-native

I want to synchronize the checklist variable in the state in ProductListScreen to the checkList in ProductScreen. So I will transfer a variable in ProductListScreen to the value in ProductScreen. How can I do that?

**ProductListScreen**

```
class ProductListScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {    checkList:'',
        };
    }
  changeList(value) {
this.setState({ checkList: value })
<ProductScreen checkList={this.state.checkList} updateCheckList={() => {
   this.setState({checkList: value})
}}>
  
}
```

**ProductScreen**

```
class ProductScreen extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {   checkList:''
        };                           
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the state via props and consume it in the child component like below.

ProductListScreen

```
class ProductListScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {    checkList:'',
        };
    }

   updateValue = (value) => {
     this.setState({checkList: value})
    }

    render(){
    return <ProductScreen checkList={this.state.checkList} 
       updateCheckList={this.updateValue('whatever')}>
    }
```

ProductScreen

```
class ProductScreen extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};                           
    }
    render(){
     //access via props
<>
     <Text>{this.props.checkList}</Text>
     <Button onPress={this.props.updateCheckList}>Update checkList</Button>
</>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, How can I do this in the function? I updated the topic